# Angular Material Virtual Repeat Strange Scrolling Behaviour

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have nested virtual repeats and it renders without problem, but I am having strange scrolling problem. If I scroll down, I cannot view all items and it jumps to another parent item. Well, it is hard to explain.

I assume that problem is the predefined height for parent items. Virtual repeat sets the same height for each item, but mine is not same height. That is why I am having the scrolling problem, but I could not find any solution that makes a dynamic height for each item(not rendering for scrolling).

I have created a pen and please try to scroll down slowly and you will understand what I mean.

Here is the link: https://codepen.io/semihgk/pen/Pzrwkj

```
        <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl"  class="content virtualRepeatStoreList" ng-app="MyApp">
          <md-virtual-repeat-container class="vertical-container" style="height:550px">
            <div md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
            <md-card flex="">
              <md-card-title>
                <md-card-title-text>
                  <span class="md-display-2">{{ item.nbr }}</span>
                </md-card-title-text>
              </md-card-title>
              <md-list style="overflow:auto;height:auto;" flex ng-cloak layout="column">
                <md-divider></md-divider>
                <md-list-item layout="row" class="noright">
                  <md-subheader flex>Item</md-subheader>
                </md-list-item>
                <md-list-item ng-repeat="it in item.items" style="max-height:40px;overflow:hidden;" class="noright">
                  <p>{{ it.nbr }}</p>
                  <md-checkbox class="md-secondary" ng-model="it.checked"></md-checkbox>
                </md-list-item>
              </md-list>
            </md-card>
          </div>
          </md-virtual-repeat-container>
        </div>
```

If anyone has any idea, I would be so appreciated. Thank you very any advice!

Comment: didu get any solution for this ? if so pls share